# IB CP WebAPI Gateway certificate change

Tags: certificate

I am trying to replace the default certificate for Interactive Brokers Client Portal WebAPI Gateway application. I am trying to install and configure the software on Windows 10 (20H2, build: 19042.685)

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Installed Java 8 Update 271
2. Downloaded the latest Gateway software, from [here](https://download2.interactivebrokers.com/portal/clientportal.gw.zip).
3. Unzipped the file to $HOME\Documents\clientportal.gw
4. Created the jks file using the following command:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore2.jks -storepass password -validity 360 -keysize 2048
```

5. Provided the details: `CN=localhost, OU=home, O=home, L=riga, ST=riga, C=lv`
6. Then exported the cer file using the following command:

`keytool -export -alias selfsigned -file mydomain2.cer -keystore keystore.jks`

7. Imported the cer file into following Local Machine certificate stores:

   7.1 Trusted Root Certification store

   7.2 Trusted Publishers store

   7.3 Personal store
8. Ran the command as per the vendor: `bin\run.bat root\conf.yaml`

Unfortunately I still get the certificate error:

Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from localhost (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Because your certificate is self-signed, that's why it is not secure; you should buy it from a reliable source. if you run your strategy on localhost, don't worry about that, but if you connect to the server remotely, then it matters